# rails bootstrap icon in a link to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use one of the icons in Bootstrap for a link_to.

These don't work::

```
<% link_to '<i class="icon-pencil"></i>', task_path(task)%>
<% link_to task_path(task), html_options = {:class => 'icon-pencil'} %>
```

I would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this other form of the `link_to` helper:

```
<%= link_to task_path(task) do %>
  <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
<% end %>
```

Make sure to include the `=` sign before the `link_to` call.